# Show duplicate results in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

My code:

```py
import random

class human:
    'humans class'
    def __init__(self,fname,lname=None,age=None):
        self.fname = fname
        if lname != None: self.lname = lname 
        else: self.lname = None
        if age != None: self.age = age 
        else: self.age = None

    def new(self,command):
        "for define a new variable"
        return exec(command)


class soccer_player(human):
    "soccer players class"
    
    all_players = []
    choised = []
    a = []
    b = []
    def __init__(self, fname, lname=None, age=None):
        super().__init__(fname, lname=lname, age=age)
        soccer_player.all_players.append(fname)
    
    def start_random_choise():
        i=0
        while True:
            choise = random.choice(soccer_player.all_players)
            if choise not in soccer_player.choised:
                soccer_player.a.append(choise)
                i = i + 1
            if i == 11:
                break
        i=0
        while True:
            choise = random.choice(soccer_player.all_players)
            if choise not in soccer_player.choised:
                soccer_player.b.append(choise)
                i = i + 1
            if i == 11:
                break

hosein = soccer_player("hosain")
maziar = soccer_player("maziar")
akbar = soccer_player("akbar")
nima = soccer_player("mina")
mehdi = soccer_player("mehdi")
farhad = soccer_player("farhad")
mohammad = soccer_player("mohammad")
khashaiar = soccer_player("khashaiar")
milad = soccer_player("milad")
mostafa = soccer_player("mostafa")
amin = soccer_player("amin")
saeed = soccer_player("saeed")
poya = soccer_player("poya")
porya = soccer_player("porya")
reza = soccer_player("reza")
ali = soccer_player("ali")
behzad = soccer_player("behzad")
sohail = soccer_player("sohail")
behrooz = soccer_player("behrooz")
shahrooz = soccer_player("shahrooz")
saman = soccer_player("saman")
mohsen = soccer_player("mohsen")

soccer_player.start_random_choise()

print("A:",end=" ")
for i in list(range(len(soccer_player.a))):
    print(soccer_player.a[i],end=" , ")
print()
print("B:",end=" ")
for i in list(range(len(soccer_player.b))):
    print(soccer_player.b[i],end=" , ")
print()
```

My problem is this app shows duplicate results:

```py
[nimafanniasl@fedora prs]$ python -u "/home/nimafanniasl/pr.py"
A: mehdi , porya , maziar , porya , akbar , porya , behzad , amin , khashaiar , maziar , ali , 
B: hosain , mohammad , mostafa , shahrooz , mostafa , poya , mostafa , hosain , farhad , hosain , hosain ,
```

This app printed 4 hesein in team B, Please help me to make this program so that it does not show duplicate results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your if condition is broken because you check the wrong list. You append players to `soccer_player.a.append(choise)` or `b` but your condition states `if choise not in soccer_player.choised`. You probably meant to append the players to the `choised` list, too.
2. You can avoid doing all this work if you replace most of this code with `random.sample` or `random.shuffle` which already guarantee you that they do not produce duplicates.

```py
    def start_random_choise():
        soccer_player.a = random.sample(soccer_player.all_players, 11)
        soccer_player.b = random.sample(soccer_player.all_players, 11)
```

3. Please look up "birthday paradox" on why your code is inefficient

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add the chosen players into `choised`. Add this line

```py
soccer_player.choised.append(choise)
```

in both while loops.